# Tor website censored at school, what can I do about it?

Tags: censorship, legal

I live in France and in my school (more likely in my [académie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_%28%C3%A9ducation%29)) the domain *.torproject.org/ is voluntary censored however I don't see any legal power that my académie have to continue blocking the Tor project website.

The blocking of the official Tor website is clearly to prevent the download and usage of Tor which can affect less tech-savvy users than me and I worry about that, the usage of this network is also not illegal in my country so I don't understand this behavior

My question is more about what can do a normal citizen to convince or force network administrators of (semi-)public networks to allow the usage of the Tor network and access to the official Tor website.

Comment: Does for example the Tor team provide letter like this one : https://www.torproject.org/eff/tor-dmca-response.html.en but for making aware network administrators that the Tor network is not only for downloading childporn or consulting jihadi forums ? If I contact the net admin I don't think he would take me seriously and will just see "one random student saying bullshit" but I think after snowden revelations no one should be blind at this point

Comment: When you have downloaded Tor you can use Bridges to connect to Tor. Just search in Google how to connect with Bridges to the Tor network

Answer (score 1):

To start off with, if your only goal is to download and run Tor; you can download it at home and place it on a USB.

If you want to get the Tor website unblocked, I would recommend speaking with the network administrator of your school about reasons why you believe it should be unblocked and maybe even convince him/her of unblocking it.

Answer (score 1):

Begin by politely asking for a written reason for the block, the process by which the decision to block was made (including the people or roles involved in making the decision) and the process for registering your dissatisfaction with the decision.

That information should help you decide how to proceed.  And perhaps you might edit your question to include that information here, when you receive it.